# Discord bot won't recognize embeds from other bots

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and I am trying to get it to react to other bots embedded messages but it is only reacting to user made embeds. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Send you code, so we can help you :)

Comment: Please make sure it does not ignore bots (e.g: if (message.author.bot) return;)